# Can incandescent light bulb can be brighter if fixed power?

Tags: electricity, electrical-engineering, luminosity

I found that luminous efficacy of 60 W tungsten incandescent bulb is 14.5 lm/W.

Is this value defined by design details listed above or it depends on something else too?

Can we design 60 W tungsten incandescent bulb, which is brighter?

How to calculate luminous efficacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent brightness of an incandescent bulb is a very strong function of the temperature of the filament, because it behaves approximately like a black body. Thus, much of the power emitted will be in the IR. The black body spectrum for different temperatures can be found, for example at [wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/BlackbodySpectrum_loglog_150dpi_en.png):

[image]

Note this is a visual representation of Planck's law. The vertical axis is logarithmic - so from 3000 K to 5777 K you get almost a 100x increase in power in the visible spectrum.

The problem, of course, is that hotter filaments have shorter life. Making a filament survive even an extra 20 K or so temperature over an equivalent life is a big deal in the incandescent bulb industry. The techniques for this are beyond the scope of this answer.

A simple thought experiment: take four light bulbs. If you just light one of them with your power source, you get a certain amount of light. If you now attach two of them in series, and make two pairs like that, you have four bulbs using the same power. However, the four bulbs will be running at a lower temperature - each gets roughly a quarter of the power. We estimate the temperature drop from the Stefan-Boltzman law which states that power $\propto T^4$, and conclude that at half the power, the temperature drops by $\left(\frac12\right)^\frac14$, or 0.84x of the original.

This means that each filament is less effective - and the total visible light output will be smaller than it was with the single filament.

**update**

You asked for a plot showing the normalized intensity. I did this for a range of values of temperature, with each plot normalized to the max and using a log-lin plot. This shows that the black body spectrum is best centered in the 400-800 nm range for a temperature of around 5200 K - hotter than any known material can be without melting. For reference I also included a "filament" of 20,000 K - as you can see, the spectrum shifts almost entirely out of the visible range.

[image]

If you are interested, the code to generate this (and with a little tweaking make others) is here:

```
# compute curves of Planck's law
import math
from scipy.constants import codata
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = codata.physical_constants

h = D['Planck constant'][0]
k = D['Boltzmann constant'][0]
c = D['speed of light in vacuum'][0]
s = D['Stefan-Boltzmann constant'][0]

pi = math.pi

def planck(T, l):
    p = c*h/(k*l*T)
    if (p > 700):
        return 0.0
    else:
        return (h*c*c)/(math.pow(l, 5.0) * (math.exp(c*h/(k*l*T))-1))

def SB(T, emissivity = 1.0):
    #  Stefan-Boltzmann law to compute total power: not used
    return emissivity * s * math.pow(T, 4.0)

Tvec = np.array( [1000,3000,3500,5237, 20000])
Lvec = np.logspace(-8, -5, 1000)

plt.figure()
# create a semitransparent "rainbow plot" to show where visible range is:
plt.imshow(np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,100),(2,1)), extent=[400, 800, 0, 1], aspect='auto', cmap='rainbow', alpha = 0.4)

# compute Planck for a range of temperatures and wavelengths
for T in Tvec:
    r = []
    for l in Lvec:
        r.append(planck(T, l))
    plt.semilogx(Lvec*1e9, r/np.max(r),label='T=%d'%T)
plt.xlabel('lambda (nm)')    
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like you have a contradiction. If you assume that temperature is uniquely related with power, then it automatically implies, that all 60 W bulbs will have same temperature and, hence, same brightness. Since it can also imply opposite, the logic is broken somewhere.

Comment: The issue is that the visible light component (which is my definition of brightness) depends on the temperature. If you have a larger area filament with a lower temperature you can emit the same amount of power but it will be most in an invisible part of the spectrum.

Comment: Aren't here any limits? For example, can I make 60 W bulb with million degrees filament? Can I emit all 60 W in gamma ray form this way?

Comment: P.S. Sure I agree with your definition of brightness.

Comment: The typical limit for a filament is the melting point (or the vapor pressure at temperatures below melting). Once you get away from that constraint - for example by using a plasma discharge - you can get hotter and brighter. But eventually light shifts to the UV. The graph shows this. Google "UV catastrophe" for more about the mechanism that limits the high frequency emission.

Comment: Suppose I have infusable material. How to make 60W filament, heating to million degrees?

Comment: It would have to be very very very small. The two problems you would run into: thermal conduction through the connecting wires, and radiation rate. Your filament would have to be approximately $300^4$ times smaller than a filament that heats to 3300K since the rate of heat loss through radiation is that much greater.

Comment: Sorry, still want to enforce the clarity. Suppose we have access to materials of any infusiness. You mean that we can make bulb the same brightness as the Sun, for example? Just make very thin filament and we will have the Sun inside? We will be able to dry the fish and brown our bodies from single bulb? Is this really true? Isn't this very thin filament become dimmed because of it's small size? And if so, doesn't this mean that there is some limit therefore?

Comment: P.S. I expect that we should redraw spectra you posted so that the area below the curves be the same for all curves (and equal to 60 W). Theses curves drawn for the body of the same surface, while we will get smaller surfaces if we want hotter filaments.

Comment: The total power emitted will still only be 60W- all that happens is that a greater fraction of that power will be at the wavelength of interesting you choose the right temperature. As you hinted, if your filament gets too hot it would end up emitting mostly in the UV and beyond.

Comment: How to ensure that current bulbs are not close to maximum? Your plot for 3000K shows maximum is already almost in visual range.